# Как подсчитать количество итераций, которые совершает метод reduce()?

Tags: javascript

Вопрос в принципе такой как в оглавлении. Нужно подсчитать количество совершеннейших итераций методом reduce. Дайте идеи пожалуйста

Comment: метод совершает ровно столько "итераций" сколько элемнтов в массиве, к которому вы его применяете

Comment: `[1,2,3].reduce(x=> x++, 0)`